# Jenkins port in RHEL Maipo is pointing to tcp6

Tags: jenkins

I have installed jenkins packages and started the service.
But i am not able to access the url.
when i am checking the ports listening, i could see that the port for jenkins is with tcp6.
How do i change it to tcp?

Comment: You may want to modify your title and text to use IPv6 and IPv4 instead of tcp6, since there is no such thing as tcp6. F.ex. "How to make Jenkins listen on a IPv4 TCP port instead of a IPv6 TCP Port".

Comment: @TomášPospíšek The name tcp6 refers to an implementation of TCP that is capable of working over IPv6. TCP is not independent of the lower level (L3) protocol it is encapsulated in, because the checksum field in the TCP header is calculated not only over the TCP segment, but also the source and destination IP addresses, among other data. This is an unfortunate layering violation we have to live with.

Comment: @JohanMyréen oh, thanks for the explanation, however, AFAICS the name tcp6 isn't used in any RFC, right? So tcp6 is not an official name, but a casual/informal one, right?

Answer (score 1):

`tcp6` means the program is using the IPv6-aware API, and so the program will be able to use that socket/port to handle both IPv6 **and** IPv4 connections, unless it specifically chooses to accept just one or the other. Most IPv6-aware programs don't do that without a good reason.

I'm guessing that the real reason you aren't able to access the Jenkins service is probably something different. RHEL has a software firewall enabled by default, and only SSH is open unless you explicitly open others. For Jenkins specifically, you would need:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=http --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Have you done that, or something similar?

Comment: Thank you for the response.
In my case FirewallD is not running.

Comment: There may still be a classic-style `iptables` firewall running, or if FirewallD has been killed instead of properly shutting it down, the rules it originally set up may still be in effect. Please run `iptables -L -vn` to verify.

Comment: i tried this but not working. meanwhile i tried to do netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN and could see the port i am trying to use for jenkins is pointing to tcp6